# Can't install Anaconda

Tags: release-juno, python

I've followed each and every step on the website: http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

However, I do not get the 7th or 8th steps below:

```
The installer prompts “Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda<2 or 3> install location to PATH in your /home/<user>/.bashrc ?” Enter Yes.

NOTE: If you enter “No”, you must manually add the path to Anaconda or conda will not work. See FAQ.

The installer describes Microsoft VS Code and asks if you would like to install VS Code. Enter yes or no. If you selected yes, follow the instructions on screen to complete the VS Code installation.
```

Also, after that, when I use anaconda-navigator, it says command not found which shows there is something wrong with my installation.

Please note that when I start a terminal, I get this:

```
bash: /home/codear/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `added'
bash: /home/codear/.bashrc: line 171: `esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer'
```

Comment: Did you trying installing with `sudo`?  In step 3, try `sudo bash`...

Comment: Yes sir, I'm using sudo while installing every trusted package. Also, how can I get rid of that the package completely to reinstall? I know only apt remove and aptitude commands but when I use 

sudo apt remove Anaconda3 or sudo apt remove anaconda-navigator nothing comes up.

Comment: To uninstall anaconda, follow the instructions here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Comment: I already deleted it. I just want to get rid of this: -rw-r--r--  1 codear codear  5643 Dec  2 12:56 .bashrc-anaconda3.bak

I don't wanna see the bash info below everytime I open a terminal

bash: /home/codear/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `added'
bash: /home/codear/.bashrc: line 171: `esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer'

Comment: Okay, I couldn't find a way to remove it from the terminal so I searched through the files and manually removed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Open the .bashrc file in your home directory.

Near the bottom of the file you will see the mentioned troublesome line:

```
esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
```

just add a newline and save, so it looks like this:

```
    esac

# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
```